# Why are parts of already plotted graphs in Animate not static?

Tags: plotting, animation

In order to reproduce the functions, that I am using in my Animate, you should use this code:

```
     n = 4;

variables = 
  Table[ToExpression["φ" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}];

xComponents = Table[Cos[variables[[i]][t]], {i, 1, n}];
yComponents = Table[-Sin[variables[[i]][t]], {i, 1, n}];

endsOfRods = 
  Table[{xComponents[[i]], yComponents[[i]]}, {i, 1, n - 1}];

xTotal = Table[
   l (Sum[endsOfRods[[i, 1]], {i, 1, j - 1, 1}] + 
      1/2 endsOfRods[[j, 1]]), {j, 2, n - 1, 1}];
yTotal = Table[
   l (Sum[If[i <= n/2, 
        endsOfRods[[i, 2]], (-1)*endsOfRods[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, j - 1, 
        1}] + If[j > n/2, (-1)*1/2 endsOfRods[[j, 2]], 
       1/2 endsOfRods[[j, 2]]]), {j, 2, n - 1, 1}];

centreOfMass = 
  Table[{xTotal[[i]], yTotal[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[xTotal], 1}];

velocityCentreOfMass = 
  Table[D[centreOfMass[[i]], t].D[centreOfMass[[i]], t], {i, 1, 
    Length[xTotal], 1}];

kineticEnergy = 
  Sum[If[i == 1 || i == n, 1/2*(1/3 m l^2)*D[variables[[i]][t], t]^2, 
    1/2 m velocityCentreOfMass[[i - 1]] + 
     1/2*(1/12 m l^2)*D[variables[[i]][t], t]^2], {i, 1, n, 1}];

potentialEnergy = 
  Sum[If[i == 1 || i == n, -m g l 1/2 Sin[variables[[i]][t]] , 
     m g yTotal[[i - 1]]], {i, 1, n, 1}](*gravity*)+ 
   Sum[If[i < n/2, 
     1/2 k (variables[[i]][t] - variables[[i + 1]][t])^2, 
     If[i == n/2, 1/2 k (variables[[i]][t] + variables[[i + 1]][t])^2,
       1/2 k (variables[[i + 1]][t] - variables[[i]][t])^2]], {i, 1, 
     n - 1, 1}](*rotational springs*);

lagrange = Simplify[kineticEnergy - potentialEnergy];
F = {0, d D[(-1)*(yTotal[[n/2 - 1]] - l/2 Sin[variables[[(n/2)]][t]]),
      t]};

r = {(xTotal[[n/2 - 1]] + 
     l/2 Cos[variables[[(n/2)]][t]]), (yTotal[[n/2 - 1]] - 
     l/2 Sin[variables[[(n/2)]][t]])};

generalizedForces = 
  Table[Simplify[F.D[r, variables[[i]][t]]], {i, 1, n/2, 1}];
equations = 
  Table[If[i <= n/2, 
    Simplify[
      Rationalize[
       D[D[lagrange, D[variables[[i]][t], t]], t] - 
        D[lagrange, variables[[i]][t]] - generalizedForces[[i]]]] == 
     0, Simplify[
      Rationalize[
       D[D[lagrange, D[variables[[i]][t], t]], t] - 
        D[lagrange, variables[[i]][t]]]] == 0], {i, 1, n - 1, 1}];

AppendTo[equations, 
  Rationalize[(-1)*(yTotal[[(n/2)]] + 
       l/2 Sin[variables[[n/2 + 1]][t]] + 
       l Sin[variables[[n]][t]])] == 0];

m = 229(*kg*);
l = 0.63(*m*);
d = 4460(*Ns/m*);
EE = 2.1*10^(11)(*Pa*);
II = 1.2*10^(-6)(*m^4*);
g = 9.81(*m/s^2*);
k = EE II/(l);

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  AppendTo[equations, variables[[i]][t] == 0 /. t -> 0]];

Pause[1];

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  AppendTo[equations, D[variables[[i]][t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0]];

Pause[3];

solution = 
  NDSolve[Rationalize[equations], 
   Table[variables[[i]][t], {i, 1, n, 1}], {t, 0, 5}];
```

Now If you are lucky, NDSolve will notify there is an error I can't get rid off but at the same time, you should get some result out of it. The error is not the reason i am writing this. The problem is with the Animate

```
Animate[Grid[{{Show[{ParametricPlot[{(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
          l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]), (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
          l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]])}, {t, 0, tmax}], 
      Graphics[{Arrow[{{l*n/2, 
           0}, {(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
              l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. 
            t -> tmax, (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
              l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. t -> tmax}}]}], 
      Graphics[{PointSize[.018], 
        Point[{(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
             l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. 
           t -> tmax, (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
             l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. t -> tmax}]}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{1.2597, l*n/2}, {0, -.025}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, 
     GridLines -> Automatic], 
    Show[{ParametricPlot[{(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
          l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]), (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
          l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]])}, {t, 0, tmax}], 
      Graphics[{Arrow[{{l*n/2, 
           0}, {(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
              l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. 

            t -> tmax, (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
              l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. t -> tmax}}]}], 
      Graphics[{PointSize[.018], 
        Point[{(l*Cos[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] + 
             l*Cos[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. 
           t -> tmax, (-l*Sin[solution[[1, 1, 2]]] - 
             l*Sin[solution[[1, 2, 2]]]) /. t -> tmax}]}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{1.25985, 1.25990}, {-0.015, -.019}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> Large, GridLines -> Automatic]}}], {tmax, 0, 3}, 
 AnimationRate -> .05]
```

Now let's focus on right plot. After some time, you can clearly see that the blue lines from the `ParametricPlot[]` move - vibrate as if they were atoms. :) I honestly don't understand why this happens nor do I know how to get rid of that. It looks funny and wrong at the same time.

Comment: A MINIMAL working (or not working) example is **much** better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your solutions.

```
φ1F, φ2F, φ3F, φ4F} = solution[[1, All, 2, 0]];
Plot[{φ1F[t], φ2F[t], φ3F[t], φ4F[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

See all that jitter in the solutions? I believe that is causing sampling jitter in the parametric plots of you `Animate` expression.